# SSO in moodle using custom server

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

There is some school that wants me to create moodle website for them 
they need the following logic

1- students are registered in their system

2- the login should be done in their system

3- when I open the login screen of moodle I should have sign in button and when student press on it I should redirect him to external login page

4- the student will enter username and password then will press login

5- the system should return code and redirect the student to a page in my system with the returned code

6- then this page in my system should make another API request with this code to get access token and student data like (email, name, etc)

7- after get Student data I should search for it in my database in moodle

8- if it is already found I should login user to my system silent and redirect the student to his dashboard

9- if it is not found I should create student to system and then log the student in silent and redirect him to his dashboard

10- on future every time student open moodle I should validate if the token is still valid or expired and if it is expired I should force student to loin again and go to #3

can anyone advice how to achieve this logic in moodle ?

I have already enable the restful web service in moodle and I found how to create user in moodle using api method , but I could not find login or logout

please help

Comment: How much money do you have? It will cost you a lot

Comment: @AksenP I am a developer work in a project in a company, of course they did not tell me the budget of the project , but why it will cost me a lot ? does it need any third party service integration or what ?

Comment: Seems like maybe this is what you need: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/OAuth_2_API . As long as your login provider supports OAuth2 then you can use it to log into a Moodle site by utilising their OAuth2 integration. If the school's login system doesn't support OAuth2 right now, you could potentially stick something like IdentityServer in front of it. (I haven't used this, it was just the result of a brief search online. Your question is a bit off-topic really, we're not here to do detailed research on your behalf, instead we'll answer specific questions about your code normally).

Comment: @ADyson I will enable it and investigate the solution you advice , Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of authentication plugins already in Moodle

https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Authentication

Including OAuth2

https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/OAuth_2_authentication

But we tend to use SAML2 which is a reliable contributed plugin from Catalyst and works with most SSO systems.

https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_saml2